# convert for loop to recursion

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, recursion

```
dict = {'dict1': [['Movie1', 'Fiction'], ['Movie2', 'Romance']], 'dict2' : [['Movie3', 'Comedy']]}
```

I have a dictionary like shown above and I'm trying to find certain element in the value according to the user input. There will be an input from user to search certain movie from the dictionary and the output will show the name, genre, and location (key) of the movie. Let say the input is `"Movie1"`, then the output will be `"Movie1"`, `"Fiction"`, and `"dict1"`. I've solved this problem using for-loop, but now I need to do it recursively. I don't have any ideas yet to solve it recursively.

This is the for-loop code that i've tried.

```
dic = {'dict1': [['Movie1', 'Fiction'], ['Movie2', 'Romance']], 'dict2' : [['Movie3', 'Comedy']]}

temp = []

movie_name = "Movie1"

for key in dic :
    value = dic[key]
    for lst in value:
        for element in lst:
            if element == movie_name:
                temp.append(element)
                movie_key = key

if movie_name in temp:
    for element in dic[movie_key]:
        if movie_name in element:
            print(f"Founded in {movie_key}; Title : {element[0]} ; Genre : {element[1]}")
```

Comment: Do not use `dict` as name of variable, you're shadowing built-in class.

Comment: If your data hast this exact structure, you won't need recursion. Could there be different nesting levels of dicts and lists?

Comment: `print("Founded in {}; Title: {}; Genre: {}".format(*next((k, n, g) for k, v in dic.items() for n, g in v if n == 'Movie1')))`

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
"I don't have any ideas" says that you need individual tutoring, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is really in just getting used to thinking about recursion and how to solve problems with it. It really is a "work backwards" kind of a solution. With that in mind, let's see if we can develop a recursive solution together.

1. Whenever you're writing something recursive, you're essentially always going to want to start at *the end* of the problem -- what will or should the behavior of the code be when it is finished, when it has found the answer? What overall environment and inputs should we expect at that final state? And, most importantly, how can we "propagate" our answer back up the call stack without losing anything we care about in the process?

   - First things first: before we can properly get started thinking about or writing any code, we need to make sure we're equipped with the right tools for the job: choosing and preparing the proper data structures (where minor differences in choice can be the difference between hacking away at an incorrect or suboptimal solution for days, or figuring out an elegant and optimal one in a few hours!) The dictionary you've provided as shown here *really* isn't doing you any favors: the values, as lists of lists, are difficult to check through cleanly and efficiently, Pythonically without a lot of cruft. Personally, I think this particular problem lends itself well to a dict of dicts, i.e.

     ```
     d = {
          'dict1': {
              'Movie1': 'Fiction',
              'Movie2': 'Romance'
           },
           etc...
         }
     ```

     considering that the dict values already form a natural association (in fact, they closely resemble a popular way of instantiating dicts: with a list of `(key, value)` tuples). If this doesn't seem like your cup of tea, I think another strategic choice would be having parallel dicts of lists -- sharing the same keys, but having one just for movie titles and one just for genres. The lists should be easy to use while coding your solution, but (unlike the nested dictionaries before -- `dict_values` and `dict_keys` are implemented as sets behind the scenes) won't make lookup quite as quick...so depending on your use case this would be less preferable. A quick illustrative example:

     ```
     movies = {'dict1': ['Movie1', 'Movie2'], 'dict2': ['Movie3']}
     genres = {'dict1': ['Fiction', 'Romance']}
     ```

     In this set-up, you'd first check through the level of dictionary *keys* and then the list *indices* of the value for the matching entry in the corresponding dictionary.

     In general, though, it can really simplify your code and your thought process to not try to cram too many different things (data with different meanings or uses) into the same object rather than having a neat, well-laid plan for utilizing a collection of objects designed to work together, especially if that can be done in a manner so as to not waste a lot of memory.

- Now that we have a general plan (the dict-of-dicts approach first described above) we can return to our original question: where do we *end* when solving this problem? What is our **base case** (important terminology as you progress with recursion)? Well, that actually seems trivially easy -- the base case is when we are looking at some collection (a `list`, `set`, `dict` keys or values, what have you) and we find that it contains the movie title we are searching for. So we can already write our base case (partially)

  ```
  def recursive_movie_search(movie, db, ...):
      if movie in db:
          return movie, db[movie]
      # Rest of search logic goes here
  ```

  Notice that because of our choice of data structure, once we've found the movie title we've already got the genre as well, since they're formally associated. We're not quite done yet though, as hinted at by the comment and the ellipsis in the function signature above.
- Here's the last challenge to the recursive technique -- how do we make it so that, by the time we find what we're looking for, we have any and all other information we need to produce our final answer? Often, as in this case, this has to do with cleverly passing along any necessary auxiliary information on our way (down the recursive call stack) to solving the problem. One simple way (not that there's only one!) to finish off the implementation in this case would be something like the following:

  ```
  def recursive_movie_search(movie, db, prev=None):
      prev = prev or []

      if movie in db:
          return prev.extend((movie, db[movie]]))
      for key in db:
          search = recursive_movie_search(movie, db[key], prev + [key])
          if search: return search

      return False
  ```

Now, to be fair, the problem as you gave it wasn't particularly well-suited to a recursive solution since the searching we needed to do was quite shallow. But the approach above should work with arbitrarily deeply nested dictionaries (then once you get the answer you can decide which of the keys along the path that led to it are significant and worth reporting, or should just be omitted). The only assumption made is that at the bottom level the movie titles will be associated with their genres.

Note also that there are several minor changes you could have made just based on personal choice: instead of accumulating the keys and passing them into the function, this could have been handled simply in the recursive call, e.g. `search = key + recursive_movie_search(movie, db[key])` but then this would have required a slightly more thorough check on the next line to ensure that we got a "hit" with that call. Also, you could just as easily return `None`, an empty list `[]`, or any other item whose boolean value evaluates to `False` (in the failure case where the movie isn't found) and this logic will work just as well. You just need *some* kind of flag there to tell you that the search failed -- you could even use a special string that you check for specifically.

P.S. This is my first answer on StackOverflow -- I really hope it helps! And I'm very much open to further questions or feedback on how I can improve :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your given structure does not change for other cases, I think this is what you are looking for:

```py
dic = {
    "dict1": [["Movie1", "Fiction"], ["Movie2", "Romance"]],
    "dict2": [["Movie3", "Comedy"]],
}

def rec_search(data, movie_name):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key in data.keys():
            result = rec_search(data[key], movie_name)
            if isinstance(result, tuple):
                return f"found in {key}; Title: {result[0]}; Genre: {result[1]}"
        return None
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for element in data:
            if isinstance(element, str):
                if element == movie_name:
                    return element
            else:
                result = rec_search(element, movie_name)
                if result:
                    return (result, element[1])
        return None


print(rec_search(dic, "Movie2"))
```